# What are all the elements of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

> What are all the elements of $A_5?$

$$\{1,(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(1,2,4),(1,4,2),(1,2,5),(1,5,2),(1,3,4),(1,4,3),(1,3,5),(1,5,3),(1,4,5),(1,5,4),(2,3,4),(2,4,3),(2,3,5),(2,5,3),(2,4,5),(2,5,4)(3,4,5),(3,5,4),(1,2) (3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3),
(2,3)(4,5),(2,4)(3,5),
(2,5)(3,4),(1,3)(4,5),(1,4)(3,5),(1,5)(3,4),(1,2)(4,5),(1,4)(2,5),(1,5)(2,4),(1,2)(3,5),(1,3)(2,5),(1,5)(2,3) \} $$

I guess the remaining ones are:
$$(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,5,4),(1,2,4,3,5),(1,2,4,5,3),(1,2,5,3,4),(1,2,5,4,3),(1,3,2,4,5),(1,3,2,5,4),(1,3,4,2,5),(1,3,4,5,2),(1,3,5,2,4),(1,3,5,4,2),(1,4,2,3,5),(1,4,2,5,3),(1,4,3,2,5),(1,4,3,5,2),(1,4,5,2,3),(1,4,5,3,2),(1,5,2,3,4),(1,5,2,4,3),(1,5,3,2,4),(1,5,3,4,2),(1,5,4,2,3),(1,5,4,3,2)   $$

Are these correct?

Comment: It is easier to read if you omit the commas.

Comment: I usually list them without comma, like instead of (3,1,2) I use (132). But that list above is what I found on proofwiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question but I think it's much more fun. 
The elements of $A_5$ are the even permutations of $S_5$. Therefore, it contains:

1. the identity
2. 3-cycles
3. 5-cycles
4. disjoint 2-cycles

Now let's count how many of each we have. 
For 2. the result is given by $$\binom{5}{3}2!=20$$
For 3. we have
$$4!=24$$
For 4. 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}/2=15$$