# Counting the elements in $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

I have a follow up question to the following post:

[What are all the elements of $A_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552344/what-are-all-the-elements-of-a-5)

In the answer there it is written that since $A_5$ contains only the even permutations, it contains:

- the identity
- 3-cycles
- 5-cycles
- disjoint 2-cycles

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, why this is the case:

Let $\sigma \in S_5$ then its decomposition into cycles can contain:

- the identity
- a 2-cycle
- a 3-cycle
- a 4-cycle
- a 5-cycle
- two disjoint 2-cycles
- one 3-cycle and one 2-cycle

There are no other possibilities, right?

Now, if I consider a $\sigma \in A_5$ it can only contain:

- the identity
- **not** 2-cycle, since the 2-cycle has signature $-1$.
- **not** 4-cycle, since the 4-cycle has signature $-1$.
- **not** one 3-cycle and one 2-cycle since the 3-cycle has signature $1$ and the 2-cycle has signature $-1$. So the signature of the composition would be $-1$.

The left possibilities are the cycles that can appear in $A_5$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be correct, but a better way to think about what elements of $S_5$ are in $A_5$ is this.

Keeping in mind that every permutation can be written as a 2-cycle or product of 2-cycles, we look for all even permutations, permutations that are a product of an even number of 2-cycles. The identity, $\epsilon$, can be written as $(12)(12)$. Therefore, $\epsilon$ is even. Clearly, 2-cycles and 4-cycles are odd permutations since $(abcd)=(ad)(ac)(ab)$ and $(ab)$ equals, well, $(ab)$. If you aren't sure about the 4-cycle equality, take a few seconds of computation to verify it.

Now any arbitrary 3-cycle, $(abc)$, can be written as $(ac)(ab)$ and any arbitrary 5-cycle, $(abcde)$ can be written as $(ae)(ad)(ac)(ab)$. So 3-cycles and 5-cycles are even and therefore, in $A_5$.

Now we look at the other two possible forms of elements in $S_5$. If an element takes the form of two disjoint 2-cycles then the element is obviously even and so it is in $A_5$. Finally, if an element is a disjoint 3-cycle and 2-cycle, then it is not even as multiplication of an odd and even permutation produces an odd permutation.

In the end, we see that in $S_5$, $\epsilon$, 3-cycles, 5-cycles, and elements that are two disjoint 2-cycles are in $A_5$. I hope this clears anything up.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks :)